# Ajax post not posting email address?

Tags: php, ajax, firefox, post

UPDATE: It will not work in Firefox, but will work on any other browser.  I even tried loading Firefox in safe mode (disabling all plugins, etc.) and still no worky. :(

I'm trying to do an AJAX post (on form submission) to a separate PHP file, which works fine without trying to send an email address through the post.  I'm fairly new to AJAX and pretty familiar with PHP.  Here's my form and ajax call

```
<form class="form" method="POST" name="settingsNotificationsForm">
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label>Email <em>*</em><small>A valid email address</small></label><input type="email" required="required" name="email" id="email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label>Email Notification<small>...when a new subscriber joins</small></label><input type="checkbox" name="subscribe_notifications" id="subscribe_notifications"> Receive an email notification with phone number when someone  new subscribes to 'BIZDEMO'
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label>Email Notification<small>...when a subscriber cancels</small></label><input type="checkbox" name="unsubscribe_notifications" id="unsubscribe_notifications"> Receive an email notification with phone number when someone  new unsubscribes to 'BIZDEMO'
                        </div>
                        <div class="action clearfix top-margin">
                            <button class="button button-gray" type="submit" id="notifications_submit"><span class="accept"></span>Save</button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

and AJAX call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $("#notifications_submit").click(function() {


                var keyword_value = '<?php echo $keyword; ?>';
                var email_address = $("input#email").val();
                var subscribe_notifications_value = $("input#subscribe_notifications").attr('checked');
                var unsubscribe_notifications_value = $("input#unsubscribe_notifications").attr('checked'); 

                var data_values = { 
                    keyword : keyword_value,
                    email : email_address,
                    subscribe_notifications : subscribe_notifications_value,
                    unsubscribe_notifications : unsubscribe_notifications_value
                };


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../includes/ajax/update_settings.php", 
                    data: data_values,
                    success: alert('Settings updated successfully!'),
                });
         });
    });
```

and receiving page:

```
<?php
include_once ("../db/db_connect.php");

$keyword = FILTER_INPUT(INPUT_POST, 'keyword' ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = FILTER_INPUT(INPUT_POST, 'email' ,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$subscribe_notifications = FILTER_INPUT(INPUT_POST, 'subscribe_notifications' ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$unsubscribe_notifications = FILTER_INPUT(INPUT_POST, 'unsubscribe_notifications' ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


$table = 'keyword_options';
$data_values = array('email' => $email, 'sub_notify' => $subscribe_notifications, 'unsub_notify' => $unsubscribe_notifications);

foreach ($data_values as $name=>$value)
{

// See if keyword is already in database table
$filter = array('keyword' => $keyword);
$result = $db->find($table, $filter);

if (count($result) > 0 && $new != true)
{
    $where = array('keyword' => $keyword, 'keyword_meta' => $name);
    $data = array('keyword_value' => $value);
    $db->update($table, $where, $data); 
}
else
{
    $data = array('keyword' => $keyword, 'keyword_meta' => $name, 'keyword_value' => $value);
    $db->create($table, $data);
    $new = true; // If this is a new record, always go to else statement
}

}

unset($value);
```

Here are some weird things that happen:

- When I only enter text into the email field, (i.e. - abc), it works fine, posts correctly, etc.
- When I enter a bogus email address with the "." before the "@", it works fine
- When I enter a validated email address (with the "." after the "@"), the post fails.

Ideas?

Comment: When you say post fails you mean that it never reaches the PHP page (as in the ajax request is halted) or you mean id doesn't return the results you were expecting?

Side Note: I dont think type="submit" is an attr for button.  I believe you are looking for input type="submit", but then you would have to kill the event default action in the click function.

Comment: I mean when i enter a true email address, email@domain.com, the post doesn't post ANYTHING.  But when I enter something like 'abc' as email address, then it posts just fine.

Comment: I did narrow it down to only NOT working in Firefox. Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Hmmm, it's been 4 hrs.  did you make any progress on it?  Try pointing your jq version at the google 1.5 version and see if that doesn't fix anything cause im using a VERY similar ajax call right now and its fine.

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @meteorainer - unfortunately, that still did not work. :(

Comment: try using GET instead of POST, just to see if it goes through. As i said i have an email validation form working using $.ajax with the above version of jq

Comment: This may not help you (which is why it's a comment, not an answer), but I had a similar problem a coupl,e of weeks ago. It turned out (after I almost ripped out all my hair in sheer frusteration) that my shared host was using mod_security (or something like that) which prevented getting (but it didn't have a problem with posting) email address and URLs. However for no reason would that work in some browsers and not others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a tutorial from a different site and rebuilding it from scratch... the jquery code below is what worked.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          $("#settingsNotificationsForm").submit(function() {

                //setup variables  
                var form = $(this),  
                formData = form.serialize(),
                formUrl = form.attr('action'),
                formMethod = form.attr('method');
                /* responseMsg = $('#signup-response') */

                //send data to server  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: formUrl,
                    type: formMethod,
                    data: formData,
                    success:function(data){
                        alert('Settings updated successfully!');
                }  
            })

            //prevent form from submitting  
            return false;

         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd first simplify things by passing in the serialized form rather than the individual vars.  It's trivial, but then again setting up all those different vars to go in individually does leave a lot of room for error.  To do it, simply do this:

```
 $.ajax({
    ...
    data:$('#formid').serialize(),
    ...
 });
```

Note that serialize sends in based on the name variable of input fields.  Ensure that those are set as you need to proceed on.

[There is a known bug with the @ symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635181/jquery-1-4-x-and-the-symbol) in older versions of jQuery.  Versioning up if you are behind might also solve the issue.

Comment: I'm on 1.4.2 of jQuery, so that isn't it.  I serialized the form and that also did not fix it. :(

Comment: I did narrow it down to only NOT working in Firefox. Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: it has a post fail on the console with an error referencing the jQuery.  Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the email address.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

I know you are using type: "POST" ,but lets just see.

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't do anything as the AJAX, type post already encodes everything, so with that, it gets "double encoded" :(

Comment: hmmm, can you give us a var_dump of the post with and without the valid email?

Comment: I did narrow it down to only NOT working in Firefox.  Any ideas why that would be?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem too.. you need to preventDefault() on the submit button.
Then continue with the posting.

```
 $("notifications_submit").click(function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  //form variables
//post via ajax
}
);
```