# Does the '@' symbol have special meaning in Javascript, Coffeescript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, grammar

I have some code that looks like

```
self = @
```

and then later on it's using `@someMethodName` or `self.someMethodName`

Does `@` have some special meaning?

Comment: Is that symbol existed in jquery?

Comment: sooo..... is it a Javascript file or a coffeescript file?

Comment: @SDC it's a coffeescript file, but presumably you could use that if Javascript had defined it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/717267

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`@` is not a valid character for a javascript identifier. Identifiers may only contain `$`, `_`, digits and letters.

In coffeescript, [`@` means `this`](https://engineering.linkedin.com/coffeescript-javascript-thats-easy-eyes-0).

> CoffeeScript has a few nice features related to the this keyword.
>   First, CoffeeScript uses the @ symbol as shorthand for this.. For
>   example, @foo is equivalent to this.foo. Second, if you use the @
>   symbol in the parameters of a function, CoffeeScript will
>   automatically assign those values as properties of the object.

Edit: As far as jQuery is concerned, the same identifier rules as javascript apply since jQuery is just javascript. For other uses of `@` in jQuery, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635181/jquery-1-4-x-and-the-symbol) or [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: It's worth adding that `@foo` means `this.foo` in CoffeeScript.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that `=>` is pretty freaking confusing when you're trying to read someone else's CoffeeScript, imho.

Answer (score 22):

`@` is shortcut for `this` in coffeescript

So

```
self = @
```

is coffeescript for:

```
var self = this;
```

Comment: which nowadays, for safety, should be `const self = @` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since the design of CoffeeScript a couple of years have passed and not everything which was proposed in CoffeeScript made it into ECMA script. Instead of being used as a shortcut for `this`, it's proposed to be used for [decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators).