# Does the @ symbol mean anything in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I noticed the @ symbols mentioned in many javascript files and couldn't figure out the significance of this character there. for example:

```
/**
    * Calls the specified callback function for all the elements in an array. The return value of
    * the callback function is the accumulated result, and is provided as an argument in the next
    * call to the callback function.
    * @param callbackfn A function that accepts up to four arguments. The reduce method calls the
    * callbackfn function one time for each element in the array.
    * @param initialValue If initialValue is specified, it is used as the initial value to start
    * the accumulation. The first call to the callbackfn function provides this value as an argument
    * instead of an array value.
*/
```

So, does the @param mean anything here? 
P.S. - The above is a description of a function with callbackfn and initialValue as parameters.

Comment: that's for doc generation purpose - take a look for exapmple at http://usejsdoc.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143123/does-the-symbol-have-special-meaning-in-javascript-coffeescript-or-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comment is [JSDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc). The `@param callbackfn` means "what follows is the description of the argument `callbackfn`".

Your IDE might be able to parse that format or you can [use jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org) to generate documentation from that.

Comment: Is there a way I could parse this JSDoc in a definition typescript file?

Answer (score 1):

It's only for documentation purpose.

@param is here to indicate which param your function will take for exemple.
There is few more, like @author, etc.

Answer (score 1):

that is a javadoc style comment. look at the javadoc documentation

Answer (score 0):

@param tag Specifies information for a parameter in a function or method.

link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-jsdoc-comments-for-javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2015